# Presented views on iOS 6 disappear. How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have two views that I present from a view controller: one for settings, one for a device log.  When I run the app on an iPad and present the view, then rotate the device, the view disappears.

If I present the view (using a button) in portrait (either one) and rotate it, it disappears. If I then present the view again, it reappears, and then rotates correctly.

Why does this happen? What can I do to fix it?

Thanks for any responses.

UPDATE: This only occurs if I first present the view in portrait mode.  If I present it in landscape mode first, it rotates just fine and doesn't disappear.

In my master view controller's viewDidLoad:

```
self.logViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogViewController"];
[self.logViewController setModalInPopover:YES];
[self.logViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self.logViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
```

My method called when the Log button is pressed:

```
- (void)showInfoView:(id)sender
{
    [self presentViewController:self.logViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Someone (I think they deleted their comment?) said that I should have the `strong` attribute set on the property for my presented view controller. I do, but I don't think that a presented view controller should always be a property.

Comment: You should almost never have strong pointers to views in IB.

Comment: Why is that? The views are accessed quite frequently, as it is a communications tool.

Comment: Its because the your view already has strong pointers to them. Your ViewController does not care about them if the view does (because the view owns them). Once the view releases them you do not want the ViewController to possess any connection to them anymore as well... hence wanting a weak pointer from your VC. If you are using an Outlet Collection then you need a strong pointer (but only because it is really an NSArray).

Comment: Are we talking about views or view controllers? I don't have strong pointers to views, just specific view controllers.

Comment: Oh my bad... I am sorry, and no you are right, the presented view controller should not always be a property, in fact I would say it normally should not be.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized what I was doing wrong.  I was presenting the presented view controller from my Master view in a SplitViewController.  By presenting it from the Detail view, the problem was solved.